# Convert jQuery code to native JavaScript- $ (window).unbind ('beforeunload')

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have custom dialogs giving users helpful information when they submit an action. (Are you sure you want to delete, etc). Firefox adds on top of this their own default alert 'are you sure you want to leave page'. Using jQuery's

```
$(window).unbind("beforeunload")
```

In combination with jQuery submit:

```
$(form).submit()
```

The unwanted default Firefox alert is prevented. What is the equivalent native JavaScript approach for this? I tried

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
});
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: Did you see `removeEventListener`?

Comment: You can try `window.onunload = window.onbeforeunload = null;`

Comment: You'll need to put a [mcve] in the question. All that that jQuery code does is remove any `beforeunload` handlers that were hooked up with jQuery. So it will only remove handlers you've put on there, which seems like a strange thing to do in this case, as you'd just...not put them on in the first place.

Comment: @SLaks- removeEventListener is not viable in this case because the it must reference a function. In this case the action is default by browser. Soit can't be removed with removeEventListener.

Comment: @T.J Crowder- I think you misunderstand. By using jquery's event propagator we were able to fire certain events, like submit, without triggering browser defaults for beforeunload..We didn't put the actions on beforeunload, firefox did. So we have to stop the default event behavior. However, cancel/preventDefault() didn't work, so I was asking for an alternative.

Comment: @user2782001: *"We didn't put the actions on beforeunload, firefox did."* No, that's incorrect. Firefox doesn't have any default `beforeunload` handlers. On a page that doesn't specifically set one, there aren't any, and you won't get the Firefox leave-the-page confirmation. So if you're getting that confirmation, code in your page is setting an `beforeunload` handler. Perhaps you're being confused by the fact that Firefox doesn't show your error message anymore. So if you `return "No! Don't leave!" from your handler, Firefox shows a dialog, but it doesn't have "No! Don't leave!" in it.